# Set default value to custom attribute for all products

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, collection, product-collection, default-values

I have created the `custom attribute (test)` for products as a text field with `default value('test')` from admin panel

And assigned that attribute to default attribute set.

Now I can able to see the new custom attribute in product edit page.

When I try to filter with the product collection

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addAttributeToFilter('test', array('like' => 'test'))->getData();
```

It return the empty array.

**My Question is :**

Is there any way to set the default value to attributes through installer script?

Why the default value is not set to that attribute?

Is there is any way to add the default values for all products?. I have more than 10,000 products in my store.

**Note :**

I don't want load the whole product collection and set value for each product.

Answer (score 11):

You could try something like this. I believe the below method is quite efficient.

```
$attrData = array(
    'attribute_code_here'=> 'Default Value Here',
);
$storeId = 0;
$productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
Mage::getModel("catalog/product_action")->updateAttributes(
    $productIds, 
    $attrData, 
    $storeId
);
```

Comment: @marius Im a huge Fan. Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: Is there is a way set this value in installer script or config.xml?

Comment: @Marius I am building a new extension. So I will create this attribute through installer script. Is this possible to set this default value in installer scritp?

Comment: @saravanavelu You could look at data scripts or create your attribute through the installer and then run the snippet as a standalone script

Comment: While installing the module, need to update the attributes is this possible without standalone script?

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody's wondering how to achieve this in Magento 2, here is the code (based on @Marius answer above)

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /** @var EavSetupFactory  */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /** @var CollectionFactory  */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /** @var Action  */
    private $action;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        Action $action
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'my_custom_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'frontend' => '',
                'frontend_class' => '',
                'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Options',
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'default' => '0',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
            ]
        );

        //set default value for the new custom attribute
        $productIds = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getAllIds();
        $this->action->updateAttributes($productIds, ['my_custom_attribute' => 0], 0);
    }
}
```