# how to add customer attribute with default values set for all existing entities?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have code like this :

```
    $setup->addAttribute('customer', 'my_custom_attr', array(
            "type" => "text",
            "backend" => "",
            "label" => "Languages for filter in layered filter.",
            "input" => "text",
            "source" => "",
            "visible" => false,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique" => false,
            "note" => "Imploded with comma array of language id's."
        )
```

attribute adds successfully but the default value is not avaliable for all existed entity:

```
    Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getFirstItem()->getMyCustomAttr(); // null
```

but attribute exists, and i am able to update it, etc.

is it possible to set it as default or I need to update all existed records manually ?

I found this [Set default value to custom attribute for all products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71469/set-default-value-to-custom-attribute-for-all-products) but here it is `Mage::getModel("catalog/product_action")` model is used to update attributes, is there some way of doing it for customer entities ?

Answer (score 0):

Please create attribute like below -

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here', array(
    'input'         => 'text', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Attribute description goes here',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
    'user_defined' => 1,
));
```

OR following working for me.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

 $setup->addAttribute('customer', 'my_custom_attr', array(
            "type" => "text",
            "backend" => "",
            "label" => "Languages for filter in layered filter.",
            "input" => "text",
            "source" => "",
            "visible" => **true**,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique" => false,
            "note" => "Imploded with comma array of language id's."
        )
 $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "my_custom_attr");
```