# How to set a default value for a attribute to all products

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, default-values

I have create an attribute "Brand Name" from `Catalog > Attribute > Manage Attribute`. I have only one brand name so i want to set that name in "Brand Name" attribute  for all the products. How can i set it, please tell me. 
Thank You.

Comment: Check this answers on: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43917/fastest-way-to-update-an-attribute-in-all-products or this one:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71469/set-default-value-to-custom-attribute-for-all-products

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing php or sql code. Or, you can do it in Admin also:

Go to `Catalog > Manage Products`, select all products and in the right you will see a select field labeled `Actions`. Select `Update Attributes` option and you will see a page that opens - all attributes a product has. 
Then, you change `"Brand Name"` attribute to desired value and save.

Tell me if there are any problems.

Comment: but i am not seeing brand name  attribute in this list

Comment: Can you see this attribute on one product?

Comment: yes i can see it

Comment: Have you added the attribute to the attribute set?

Comment: yes i have added it to the attribute set

Comment: Check how are other attributes that do appear in the list made and do the same with your attribute. Clear the cache, reindex...

Comment: i have tried same like other attributes but still i can't see it in the list

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to assign the "Brand Name" attribute **to all the attribute sets** in your system. 
Afterwards, go to the products grid in the admin, click "Actions -> Update Attributes". You should be able to update the value of your attribute.