# Programmatically added attribute, default value enabled

Tags: product-attribute

My patch adds new attribute to products.
I want it to be enabled on every product by default.
However, it is always disabled on sample data products and works as intended when I try to add a completely new product from the admin panel.
How to fix it?

```
<?php

namespace Alex\AskQuestion\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidateException;

class AddAskQuestionAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * AddAskQuestionAttribute constructor.
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory          $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Adding new attribute to product
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws ValidateException
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'allow_to_ask_questions',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Allow to ask question',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => Boolean::class,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'sort_order' => 90,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 1,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getVersion(): string
    {
        return '1.0.2';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352598/113640) solved my issue.

```
 //set default value for the new custom attribute
        $productIds = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getAllIds();
        $this->action->updateAttributes($productIds, ['allow_to_ask_questions' => 1], 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your new attribute is enabled by default for all products, You can do this by creating a separate method in your patch class to update the attribute value for existing products.

```
private function updateDefaultAttributeValue()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $product->setData('allow_to_ask_questions', 1);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'allow_to_ask_questions');
    }

    $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help. attribute is created for sample data products but remains disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'allow_to_ask_questions',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Allow to ask question',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => Boolean::class,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'sort_order' => 90,
                'user_defined' => false,
//                'default' => 1,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );

        $defaultValues = [
            'allow_to_ask_questions' => 1,
        ];

        foreach ($defaultValues as $attributeCode => $defaultValue) {
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                Product::ENTITY,
                $attributeCode,
                'default',
                $defaultValue
            );
        }
    }
```